# Sorting the values of a variable without displaying the data

Tags: r

I want to sort a variable `x` with `length(x)>12000`. When I run

```
sort(x)
```

from RStudio, the `r` console starts to display the result. Is there a way I can sort without displaying the sorted data?

Comment: Why not just store it as a new variable? `y <- sort(x)`?

Comment: you can use `invisible(sort(x))`, but I don't understand why though, unless your function updates the values by reference.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I am a newbie, I got it now.

Comment: @Duna, no problem. I didn't post as an answer because I wasn't sure if that was what you're looking for. Please feel free to add the answer on your own and *accept* it if it is what you were looking for. Doing so helps keep the "unanswered" queue manageable. Thanks.

Comment: @Arun: Does R let you update variables by reference? Except for `data.table`.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a broader over-arching question here which is that of the R REPL. You see you are in a Read-Eval-Print Loop in the R interpreter. What it does is:

- Reads the input that you have given: `sort(x)`
- Evaluates the input: finds the sorted vector.
- Prints the output.
- Loops over.

Therefore, when you create a valid `object` in the interpreter it gets printed whether you explicitly call `print` or not.

```
> x <- 5
> x
[1] 5
> print(x)
[1] 5
```

The only thing that does not get printed is an *assignment* because, *technically*, that is a side-effect. Therefore the first statement `x <- 5` does not say anything.

Here is an interesting toy to play with:

```
> f1 <- function (x) x
> f2 <- function (x) y <- x

> f1(5)
[1] 5

> f2(5) # Nothing
```

The subtle difference is that f1 explicitly `return`s `x` while f2 is only using x for a side effect. However if you were to do `identical(f1(5), f2(5))` you will get `TRUE`.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is not quite correct.  `f2` returns the value of the last statement, but does so invisibly.  Try this:  `f2(5) ; .Last.value` to see that the value is available.

Comment: I agree. Which is why I added the `identical(f1(5), f2(5))` there.

Answer (score 1):

I learned that I could simply store the sorted data in a new variable; such as `y <- sort(x)`. Using `invisible(sort(x))` is also another option.

Comment: Except that the latter doesn't do anything useful, as `sort(x)` does not modify `x` .